# Terraform Google Uptime check module - how to specify a region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, monitoring, terraform-provider-gcp, uptime

I want to specify a region for uptime check to run . I specified argument `selected_regions` and assigned value "North America" but getting the below error

---

My terraform code

```
resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "http1" {
  project      = var.project_id
  display_name = "Website uptime check1"
  timeout = "10s"
  period = "60s"
  selected_regions = [var.region1]
  http_check {
    path = "/"
    port = "80"
  }
  monitored_resource {
    type = "uptime_url"
    labels = {
      project_id = var.project_id
      #region     = var.region
      host = "xx.xx.xx.xx"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Error

```
Step #1 - "terraform-apply": Error: Error updating UptimeCheckConfig "projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/uptimeCheckConfigs/website-uptime-check-vh-T7eowa2Y": googleapi: Error 400: Invalid value at 'uptime_check_config.selected_regions[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.monitoring.v3.UptimeCheckRegion), "North America"
Step #1 - "terraform-apply": Details:
Step #1 - "terraform-apply": [
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":   {
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":     "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":     "fieldViolations": [
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":       {
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":         "description": "Invalid value at 'uptime_check_config.selected_regions[0]' (type.googleapis.com/google.monitoring.v3.UptimeCheckRegion), \"North America\"",
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":         "field": "uptime_check_config.selected_regions[0]"
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":       }
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":     ]
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":   }``
Step #1 - "terraform-apply": ]
Step #1 - "terraform-apply":
```

Answer (score 2):

Try entering region like listed in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/uptime-checks/using-uptime-checks#monitoring_uptime_check_list_ips-api):

> USA, EUROPE, SOUTH_AMERICA, or ASIA_PACIFIC

Comment: Looks like the link you shared is not the correct one! is it?

Comment: I meant to point to the 'API' tab. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The list is quite difficult to find. As of 31/08/2023, it is here:

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.uptimeCheckConfigs#UptimeCheckRegion

- REGION_UNSPECIFIED
- USA EUROPE
- SOUTH_AMERICA
- ASIA_PACIFIC
- USA_OREGON
- USA_IOWA
- USA_VIRGINIA

Example of use:

```
variable "list_uptime_check_regions" {
  type = list
  description = "List of regions from which the check will be run."
  default = [ "EUROPE", "ASIA_PACIFIC", "SOUTH_AMERICA" ]
}

resource "google_monitoring_uptime_check_config" "https_incident" {
  display_name = "uptime-check_test"
  selected_regions = var.list_uptime_check_regions  
  timeout = "60s"
  ...
}
```